# Calling SendInput() results in unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, winapi

Calling `SendInput` to simulate pressing down left click appears to be executed after code written below said call to `SendInput` is executed.

I made a listbox and I want right click to select items from the list box so I decided to make the message `WM_CONTEXTMENU` call `SendInput` to simulate a left click immediately before opening a context menu, but I believe the context menu is popping up before the left click occurs, resulting in the left click clicking the edge of the context menu (which does nothing).

Adding `MessageBox(0,0,0,0);` right in between the call to SendInput and the creation of the popup menu results in the left click successfully occurring and selecting an item, this is the behaviour I expected and desire. Strangely calling `Sleep(1000)` after the call to SendInput delays the program but doesn't cause the SendInput to behave as expected.

EDIT: Yes I know one solution to my problem is to select it using LB_SETSEL, but I'm partially doing this for learning purposes and if I run into a similar problem using SendInput I want to know how to solve it, so please help me resolve this specific bug.

Comment: I recommend not spending too much time debugging this problem, since this is really an [X-Y situation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Simulating a mouse click is not a reasonable way of selecting items from a context menu. Why can't you just select the items through the normal programmatic API for a ListBox?

Comment: `MessageBox` pumps messages, `Sleep` does not. Understanding your problem requires a good understanding of Windows message queues. But as Cody says you are surely doing this the wrong way and the best way for you to proceed is to find the right solution to your problem, whatever it really is.

Comment: If you want to understand why your program behaves as it does you need to understand message queues. Do you understand queues?

Comment: I suppose not to the extent that I should, any suggested reading material?

Answer (score 2):

`SendInput()` merely injects keystrokes into the keyboard's input buffer and then exits immediately, letting your app do other things while Windows handles the keystrokes in the background as if the user had typed them manually.  That is not the solution to your problem.

In your `WM_CONTEXTMENU` handler, simply send a [`LB_SETCURSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761342.aspx) message (for a single-select ListBox) or a [`LB_SETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761352.aspx) message (for a multi-select ListBox) directly to the ListBox's HWND to select the desired list item(s) before then displaying your popup menu.